# How to create grids using Total rows and columns in android dynamically

Tags: java, android, image, gridview

I am new to android. I want to build a grid based on total rows and columns and display in view.After creating a grid I need to place icon in one of the grid. The icon will come from the server URL. The grid should be like this below. [image]

That created grid should fit in the screen. How do I do that? Can someone give me a code sample. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

res/layout/ gridview_android_example_with_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_android_example"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidGridViewDisplayImages.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGridViewDisplayImages extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView androidGridView;


// Dummy Array of images (Replace with your own values)
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.email, R.drawable.mobile, R.drawable.alram,
            R.drawable.android, R.drawable.wordpress, R.drawable.web,
            R.drawable.email, R.drawable.mobile, R.drawable.alram,
            R.drawable.android, R.drawable.wordpress, R.drawable.web,
            R.drawable.email, R.drawable.mobile, R.drawable.alram,
            R.drawable.android, R.drawable.wordpress, R.drawable.web,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_android_example_with_image);

        androidGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_android_example);
        androidGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterGridView(this));

        androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Grid Item " + (position + 1) + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapterGridView extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapterGridView(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView mImageView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
                mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                mImageView.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
            } else {
                mImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return mImageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo so much @Akshay Chopde. I do not want to display images in the grid. Only one icon i have to place inside the grid. /* Integer[] imageIDs = {}*/ this is empty array in my case. How do I build grid without this? Will it work?

Comment: You required an list of data which contains the set of images. So that you can iterate to the size of list and set each of the image in an list to the cell of grid.